# Is there a more optimized and faster way to read through and analyze text files in C#?

Tags: c#, .net-core, string-matching, readline, streamreader

I am in the process of writing a C# netcoreapp3.1 Windows Forms program to try to analyze some Database extracts that I created from another process.  The Database queries I am running that generate the extract files just output two key pairs to a plain text file similar to this:

ACCOUNT_NUMBER USER_ID

The queries end up generating 20 files total from two different Tables in the Database that I am trying to compare.  Each Database Table ends up being split into 10 different files based on the ACCOUNT_NUMBER.  Each file contains over 1 million lines of key pairs.

My C# program is attempting to read through each line of the Database extracts from the first Table and try to find a match for it in the second Table.  Because I have split each Table into 10 parts, I can narrow down which file I need to search through based on the last digit of the ACCOUNT_NUMBER.  However, I still need to read through over a million lines in each text file in order to find if there is a matching Record or not.  Further complicating the issue is that for each extract file from Table 1, the ACCOUNT_NUMBER could be in any one of the 10 extract files for Table 2, so I can't really do batch checking for each extract file for Table 2.  (Or at least I haven't figured out a way of doing it yet.)

I was told that C# *SHOULD* be able to handle reading through millions of lines in a text file pretty quickly, but while testing my program, it is running **HORRENDOUSLY SLOW** for some reason!  The program ended up running for over **27 HOURS** (1,648 minutes) just to finish analyzing the FIRST Database extract for the first Table!!  Why is it taking so long to read through these text files?  After completing the first extract file from Table 1, the counters in my program said that it read 1,165,880 Records and found 1,165,402 matching Records in the second Table (in any one of the 10 extract files), which means that Table 2 is missing 478 Records.

Is there a faster way to either read through these text files than the way I am currently doing it or a way to load the text files into memory to be able to access them faster?  Due to the size of the files I am dealing with (each text file is around 25 MB in size and as I previously mentioned, there are 20 files total), I was worried that attempting to read each file in once and storing each key pair into a DataTable or even a string[] array or something like that would run into memory overflow errors.

I was also thinking of possibly modifying each text file extract from Table 2 to delete the key pair that was found from the file whenever it finds a match to reduce the number of records that it needs to read through on each subsequent run through the extract files.  However, I don't know if that would actually slow the program down even further having to write out the text file every time it finds a match?

Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated!  I have pasted the relevant parts of my code below for your review.  Just a little background on what I am doing here, this program calls the OpenFileDialog() method to allow the user to select each of the 10 extract files needed for each Database Table and it loads the file paths and filenames into textboxes on the Form.  Then when the user clicks a button to actually start the analysis, it loops through each of these textboxes and calls a function to read through each file line-by-line by passing the filename to the function.

Here is the code from the main Form:

```c#
int clientrecordsread;
int duplicateusersrecordsread;
int totalexactduplicateusers;
int totalusersrecordsexist;
int totalmissingusersrecords;
int totalrecordsinerror;
TextBox[] txtClientExtractToe = new TextBox[] { txtClientToe0, txtClientToe1, txtClientToe2, txtClientToe3, txtClientToe4, txtClientToe5, txtClientToe6, txtClientToe7, txtClientToe8, txtClientToe9 };
TextBox[] txtUserExtractToe = new TextBox[] { txtUserToe0, txtUserToe1, txtUserToe2, txtUserToe3, txtUserToe4, txtUserToe5, txtUserToe6, txtUserToe7, txtUserToe8, txtUserToe9 };

public void ReadClientRecords(string clientfilename)
{
    // Define variables needed to analyze LOUIS II Extract files:
    string usertoefilename;
    string clientrec;
    string[] splitrec;
    string clientuserid;
    string clientacctno;
    int usertoe;
    int usermatchesfound;

    try
    {
        using (StreamReader readClient = new StreamReader(clientfilename))
        {
            while ((clientrec = readClient.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                // Using the string.Split() method here to split the clientrec into individual fields:
                splitrec = clientrec.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                if ((splitrec.Length) == 2)
                {
                    clientuserid = splitrec[0];
                    clientacctno = splitrec[1];
                    usertoe = (int)char.GetNumericValue(clientacctno[8]);
                    if ((usertoe >= 0) && (usertoe <= 9)) 
                    {
                        clientrecordsread++;
                        usertoefilename = txtUserExtractToe[usertoe].Text;
                        usermatchesfound = FindUserRec(usertoefilename, clientacctno, clientuserid);
                        switch (usermatchesfound)
                        {
                            case -1:  // There was an error processing the User Record Extract for this Toe.
                                totalrecordsinerror++;
                                break;
                            case 0:  // No matching User Record was found for this ACCOUNT-NO.
                                totalmissingusersrecords++;
                                break;
                            case 1:  // Only 1 matching User Record was found for this ACCOUNT-NO.
                                totalusersrecordsexist++;
                                break;
                            default: // More than 1 matching User Record was found for this ACCOUNT-NO.
                                totalusersrecordsexist++;
                                totalexactduplicateusers = totalexactduplicateusers + usermatchesfound;
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       string errortext = "An error was encountered while reading the CLIENT Extract File: " + System.Environment.NewLine + clientfilename + System.Environment.NewLine + "The ACCOUNT-NO read from the input file is invalid: " + clientacctno;
                        MessageBox.Show(errortext, "Error Reading CLIENT Extract", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    string errortext = "An error was encountered while reading the CLIENT Extract File: " + System.Environment.NewLine + clientfilename + System.Environment.NewLine + "The record format of the input file is invalid. " + System.Environment.NewLine + "Last record read from input file: " + clientrec;
                    MessageBox.Show(errortext, "Error Reading CLIENT Extract", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        string errortext = "Error - Unable to open the CLIENT Extract File: " + System.Environment.NewLine + clientfilename + System.Environment.NewLine + e.Message;
        MessageBox.Show(errortext, "Error Opening CLIENT Extract File", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}

public int FindUserRec( string usertoefilename, string clientacctno, string clientuserid)
{
    // Define variables needed to analyze LOUIS II Extract files:
    string userrec;
    string usersuserid;
    string usersacctno;
    int nummatchesfound = 0;

    try
    {
       using (StreamReader readUsers = new StreamReader(usertoefilename))
       {
            while ((userrec = readUsers.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                // Rather than trying to use string.Split() to create an array of strings,
                // try using the string.SubString() method to return each field from the file:
                if ((userrec.Length) >= 18) // Error checking to be sure the Record read in from the file is long enough.
                {
                    usersuserid = userrec.Substring(0,8);  // Since the fields are fixed-width, we can hard code the values.
                    usersacctno = userrec.Substring(9,9);  // Skipping over the space between the two fields in the input record.
                    if (usersacctno == clientacctno)
                    {
                        if (usersuserid == clientuserid)
                        {
                            nummatchesfound++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            duplicateusersrecordsread++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    string errortext = "An error was encountered while reading the Users Extract File: " + System.Environment.NewLine + usertoefilename + System.Environment.NewLine + "The record format of the input file is invalid. " + System.Environment.NewLine + "Last record read from input file: " + userrec;
                    MessageBox.Show(errortext, "Error Reading Users Extract", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            return nummatchesfound;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        string errortext = "Error - Unable to open the Users Extract File: " + System.Environment.NewLine + ssntoefilename + System.Environment.NewLine + e.Message;
        MessageBox.Show(errortext, "Error Opening Users Extract File", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return -1;
    }
}

private void btnAnalyze_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string clientfilename;
    // Initialize program counters:
    clientrecordsread = 0;
    duplicateusersrecordsread = 0;
    totalexactduplicateusers = 0;
    totalusersrecordsexist = 0;
    totalmissingusersrecords = 0;
    // Process the Client Record Extract files for each Toe populated in the textboxes:
    for (int x = 0; x <= 10; x++)
    {
        clientfilename = txtClientExtractToe[x].Text;
        ReadClientRecords(clientfilename);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know that it's the reading of the text files that takes time?

Comment: There are many possible answers, and any of them would just be a guess. Try to isolate your disk I/O from your processing and write some unit tests. Step through with the debugger. If all else fails, fire up the [profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/profiling-feature-tour?view=vs-2022).

Comment: 25 MB today is not a problem. If you have 20 files, we are talking about 500 MB. Load all in memory. I have applications running in servers that manage 2 GB only to get more performance and do less queries to database.

Comment: I just read through your code in a little more detail. It looks like for every line in the first file, you're reading the entire second file. That's a very likely culprit. If this data is coming from a database, why aren't you doing this inside the database? Matching up related data is exactly what databases excel at. To get the same performance outside the database, you'll have to come up with your own way of indexing the data.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede - Because as far as I know, there is no way to do this inside the Database that I am getting this data from. I am trying to analyze data from an old Network Database architecture, not a Relational Database. The query program that I am using to generate these extracts also cannot perform this required analysis as I have tried to do that within the confines of that program. It works fine to find matching records, but it doesn't do too well with finding records where there is no match.

Comment: @VashtheStampede re your reply to Kevin's comment: then how about migrate your data into a different database?

Comment: Another thought I had was I was wondering if there is a way to open all 10 files for Table 2 one time, then just do multiple reads through each file as many times as necessary and close them all at the end when I am done with them.  Is this possible in C# and would this save any processing time not having to close and re-open the files for every read?  When you get to the EOF, is there any way to reset the "pointer" to where the StreamReader will start reading to the beginning of the file for the next loop through the file to find the next matching Record?

Comment: @Jonathan - That is also not possible.  The best I could do would be to generate the extract files, then have my C# program load the data from the extract files into a SQL Server Database and then try to use SQL commands to do the analysis I need to.  However, I was told that this should not be necessary and would be more difficult and slower than just reading through the text files to try to find all of the matches.

Comment: As said before: Parsing an entire huge file for every line of another huge file will dig your performance grave. Store the lines of the files while you parse each once as records in a Db (with EF Core if you like), and then query the Db.

Comment: Then I'd try to emulate what a relational DB would do. Build an index for your second file. If you can't keep the entire file in memory, at least keep the index in memory. This should greatly improve performance over reading the entire file in every call to `FindUserRec`.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @VashtheStampede when I said 'migrate into a different database' I didn't necessarily mean do a whole data export/import external of your application. I mean have a small SQL express or whatever DB beside your app; use your app to parse the records; and write them into your db (with EF or whatever). Then `FindUserRec()` becomes `db.UserRec.Count(i => i.UserAcctNo == ClientAcctNo && i.UserUserId == ClientUserId);` That's it. That's the whole logic. As others have mentioned, the way to increase performance is for you to add indexing, etc. Basically to recreate DB logic in your app

Answer (score 0):

As others already pointed out the problem: you're literally reading again and again that big file inside your second method. For each loop on ReadClientRecords(); you are running FindUserRec(); that loops again inside another text-file, that's exponentially rises your process time, since you're literally running a million lines for each line of your first file.

If you need to compare FILE 1 with FILE 2, load them in memory. If you're using each line for searching data, then load them inside arrays for you to loop and find the desired data. That alone will decrease process-time by ALOT.

Try to avoid using big-data at anything other than memory.Memory will be (almost) better in most case-scenarios.